# Non-FQDN Intranet Subdomain

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, windows-dns

I have a production server and a development server. Each has their own CNAME record so employees don't have to type in the NetBIOS name of each machine. Lets say they're `myapp` and `myappdev`. I've set up IIS with a number of virtual hosts so I have multiple development sites (so I can test different branches). I want to give each of these a subdomain, such as `alpha.myappdev`, etc. So I had the domain admin set up various subdomains of `myappdev`. When I run `nslookup alpha.myappdev`, I get the results I expect. When I run `ping alpha.myappdev`, I get an error that the host couldn't be resolved. When I run `ping alpha.myappdev.mycompanyintranet.local`, it works.

Is there a way to get **non-fully qualified intranet subdomains** to work?

I am not interested in answers that involve non-intranet (sub)domains, FQDNs, or something other than subdomains (such as `alpha-myappdev`), etc.

The DNS records are set up like `alpha.tracedev` => `tracedev.mycompanyintranet.local.`.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly then it seems that this is what you're looking for: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731744.aspx

Comment: Note well that it is best practice to _always_ use fully qualified domain names, everywhere. And of course it is best practice to _not_ use .local but to use a domain your company owns.

Comment: The choice to use .local is not mine. I'm trying to avoid FQDNs because they would involve mycompanysobnoxiouslylongname.local.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command-line `nslookup` tool doesn't use the operating system's own DNS resolver API, so what you're seeing w/ `nslookup` returning what you'd expect for `alpha.myappdev` isn't surprising.

The OS DNS resolver API assumes that names that contain a dot (that is, a *multi-label* name) are qualified and doesn't append the DNS search suffix automatically. You can change this behavior in Windows Vista (and newer versions) using the Group Policy setting "Allow DNS Suffix Appending to Unqualified Multi-Label Name Queries" located under "Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Network / DNS Client". Enabling that setting will cause the resolver to do what you're looking for.