# DNS suffix works only when no subdomains are added

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, internal-dns

We have a DNS suffix for our domain `ourdomain.local` and it works whenever we have one additional DNS component e.g. `test1.ourdomain.local` or `graphs.ourdomain.local`, so that means we only have to type `test1` or `graphs` and it will resolve correctly. However if we have `remote.graphs.ourdomain.local` then `remote.graphs` won't resolve and only `remote.graphs.ourdomain.local` will.

This is a Windows Server 2012R2 deployment. **However, the problem seems to be client side**, since Linux clients are able to resolve `remote.graphs` correctly, yet Windows ones are not. The Linux clients are not managed by group policy or anything, they just have manual configuration for the DNS:

```
options ndots:3
nameserver 192.168.123.123
nameserver 8.8.8.8
search ourdomain.local
```

where I believe `options ndots:3` is enabling the resolution to work correctly for subdomains in Linux. I am looking for the equivalent of `options ndots:3` or similar for Windows clients. What kind of configuration do I need to set in group policy to enable correct resolution?

Notes:
[/etc/resolv.conf option `options ndots:N` is detailed here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf):

```
[...]
sets a threshold for the number of dots which must appear in a name
given to res_query(3) (see resolver(3)) before an initial absolute
query will be made. The default for n is 1, meaning that if there are 
any dots in a name, the name will be tried first as an absolute name 
before any search list elements are appended to it. The value for this
option is silently capped to 15.
[...]
```

**EDIT w/ SOLUTION:**

[The solution consists in enabling *AppendToMultiLabelName* in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient as a REG_DWORD with value 1](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.DNSClient::DNS_AppendToMultiLabelName) - this can be done locally, or if enabled through GPO via *"Allow DNS Suffix Appending to Unqualified Multi-Label Name Queries" located under "Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Network / DNS Client".*

[I found the answer here (another question on serverfault)](https://serverfault.com/questions/643588/non-fqdn-intranet-subdomain)

Comment: Do the Windows clients have a DNS suffix search order specified? It seems like they don't and you are referring to normal DNS devolution instead.

Comment: @GregAskew I've checked and it seems no DNS suffix is specified through group policy via DNS client parameters set by administrative templates in the group policy. I will set the DNS suffix here instead and see if there is a difference with DNS devolution. I'll report back, thanks.

Comment: A note; To set the option I suggest via the DHCP if you can, that would allow the computer to refresh the GPO and other policy more easily as it would already know where to lookup for them. In GPO you have to assume it will find the server before it apply the GPO, and in a reboot if you change settings the computer might have difficulty to find the correct place.

Comment: I found the answer. @yagmoth555 I did look whether I could set this up via DHCP but I think by default that option was not in the list for Windows DHCP server. However I'm not sure if it *could* be added.

Answer (score 2):

[The solution consists in enabling *AppendToMultiLabelName* in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient as a REG_DWORD with value 1](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.DNSClient::DNS_AppendToMultiLabelName) - this can be done locally, or if enabled through GPO via *"Allow DNS Suffix Appending to Unqualified Multi-Label Name Queries" located under "Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Network / DNS Client".*

[I found the answer here (another question on serverfault)](https://serverfault.com/questions/643588/non-fqdn-intranet-subdomain)

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking for a solutions like this for a long time!

Comment: Also searchg for years to solve this. I've tried this and most other gp policies there but still no ping or Resolve-DnsName  -Name <host> result. Only works with the dot which i refuse to use.